# PHP Select Value & Redirect With If Statement

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement

I'm trying to create a php scipt that checks if members are verified as they land on a page. If they are not they get redierected to login with an error message & instructions.  So on the page I have this code:

```
<?php
    if (loggedin()) {
        $check_active = "SELECT active FROM members WHERE username == '$username'";
        $active = mysql_query($check_active);
        if ($active < 1) {
            header("Location: login.php?verify=true");
        } else {
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

It is redirecting the user back to the login page but it doing it whether they are active or not.  The values for active members are 0(not verified) & 1(verified).  Is htere something wrong in the script I'm using?

Thank You

Comment: You're not fetching a row from the query result.

Comment: does `==` work in this context?

Comment: $active is always less than 1 because the integer value of the resource (not an integer) returned by mysql_query is always 0. Second, mysql_ functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and should be replace with odbc_connect, ADO, or PDO object connections.

Comment: You are assigning the mysql_query retuned value to the variable. mysql_query returns Zero if the statement was successful. Nonzero if an error occurred. What happens here is it will not authenticate user if the username is valid. You should fetch a row as @jeroen said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to handle the `$active` result and put it into a PHP variable/array. `$active` as it is in your code is simply a *resource* (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)) Try this:

```
$active = mysql_query($check_active); // run query and return resource

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($active);  // put resource data into php array   

if ($row['active'] < 1) {
    header("Location: login.php?verify=true");
} else {
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use old `mysql`, use `mysqli_` or read topic on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php.

Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't fetching the data correctly after the query.

Right after you do the the mysql_query function. Try this:

```
$output = mysql_fetch_assoc($active);
$active_result = $ouput['active'];
```

Don't know if it might work.

And add a little more security for SQL injection there.
And use MySQLi instead since you aren't keen on preventing SQL injection yourself.